# extracting majority text from multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame below and want to extract the majority of entries from multiple columns.

lets say from column a:e  i want to check what are the majority of entries for example 4 or 0 , then create a new column and update it to majority of answer.

```
df <- data.table(id = 1:7,
                 reg = c("DD","BB","MA","CA","MN","KA","LA")         
                 , a = c(4,4,0,4,0,4,0)
                 , b = c(0,4,0,4,0,4,0)
                 , c = c(4,0,4,4,4,4,0)
                 , d = c(0,4,0,4,0,4,4)
                 , e = c(0,4,4,4,0,4,0)
                 , card = c("two","three","one","one","two","three","six")
                 
)
```

required output should be look like

[image]

Comment: how to handle ties?

Comment: checked but not working, there will not be any tie i am sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
d <- df[, 3:7]
v <- t(table(unlist(d), row(d)))
df$maj <- as.numeric(colnames(v))[max.col(v)]
```

or

```
df %>%
    mutate(maj = {
        (.) %>%
            select(a:e) %>%
            {
                t(table(unlist(.), row(.)))
            } %>%
            {
                as.numeric(colnames(.))[max.col(.)]
            }
    })
```

and you will obtain

```
> df
   id reg a b c d e  card maj
1:  1  DD 4 0 4 0 0   two   0
2:  2  BB 4 4 0 4 4 three   4
3:  3  MA 0 0 4 0 4   one   0
4:  4  CA 4 4 4 4 4   one   4
5:  5  MN 0 0 4 0 0   two   0
6:  6  KA 4 4 4 4 4 three   4
7:  7  LA 0 0 0 4 0   six   0
```

Comment: if i want to mutate the dataframe then ..??

Comment: @samrr_tr see update

Comment: one last question sir , if i want to check and mutate df if any of the column have 4 the update maj to 4 else 0 then ..??

Comment: @samrr_tr not sure if got your point: maj is 4 if there is at least one 4 in columns `a` to `e`?

Comment: yes ,correct the same

Comment: @samrr_tr then the idea should be using `df$maj <- ifelse(rowSums(df[, 3:7]==4)>0, 4, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  counts <- sort(table(x))
  return(names(counts[length(counts)]))
}

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(maj = fun(c_across(3:7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, we can use a rowwise operation and create the new column with the statistical *mode*.
We can use the function `mfv` (most frequent value) from the `modeest` package, or calculate the mode manually, as suggested [all across SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/how-to-find-the-statistical-mode), including a solution in other answers here.

```
library(dplyr)
library(modeest)

df |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(maj = mfv(c_across(a:e))) |> 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 × 9
     id reg       a     b     c     d     e card    maj
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 DD        4     0     4     0     0 two       0
2     2 BB        4     4     0     4     4 three     4
3     3 MA        0     0     4     0     4 one       0
4     4 CA        4     4     4     4     4 one       4
5     5 MN        0     0     4     0     0 two       0
6     6 KA        4     4     4     4     4 three     4
7     7 LA        0     0     0     4     0 six       0
```